# Folder already exist, but it is not a Subversion repository error in Ansible Subversion checkout

Tags: svn, ansible

I am trying to checkout a SVN repository from my repository server using Ansible subversion module. I already configured one svn repository in my server. And I am trying to checkout that into my Ec2 machine using Ansible playbook and subversion module. But when I am running the playbook, I am getting the error that:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR: ././ folder already exists, but its not a subversion repository."}
```

My Ansible role tasks contain the following:

```
- name: SVN checkout
  subversion:
   repo: <my-ip>/svn/test
   checkout: yes
   update: yes
   dest: ././
```

I am getting error like the following,

[image]

**Updated Observation**

When I am only exporting using " export: yes " option, it's properly working. The problem is only for checkout operation.

My confusion is that, Is there any problem for my checkout using above YML? Why only showing these type of error ? Since export also properly working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to checkout to a non-empty folder you should be using `in_place`, this option was added in 2.6 release, specifically [this PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/38366).

Try addin `in_place = yes` to your option list.

```
- name: SVN checkout
  subversion:
   repo: <my-ip>/svn/test
   checkout: yes
   update: yes
   in_place: yes
   dest: ././
```

Double check if anything gets overwritten, this is doing a `svn checkout --force` under the hood.

[2.6 docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/subversion_module.html)

> **in_place** default value: no
>
> If the directory exists, then the working copy will be checked-out
> over-the-top using svn checkout --force; if force is specified then
> existing files with different content are reverted